# Twitter and dribble anchors not working on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a div with four icons pointing to twitter, dribbble, GitHub and Gmail respectively. I have wrapped them around anchor tags to create links to these websites. I notice that the links work perfectly across all browsers on desktop, but on mobile, only GitHub works, and the Gmail icon opens up the default mail app on the phone. The twitter and dribbble icons dont work.

I checked the `pointer-events`in css and they are set to auto, and I can't find any reason whatsoever why two of the links won't work.

Any help would be most appreciated! Thank you!

HTML:

```
<div class="social-img-div">
     <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/hackertronix">
        <img src="images/twitter-icon.svg" class="social-img twitter-img">
     </a>
     <a target="_blank" href="https://dribbble.com/hackertronix">
        <img src="images/dribbble-logo.png" class="social-img svg-size">
     </a>
     <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/hackertronix">
        <img src="images/github-logo.png" class="social-img svg-size">
     </a>
     <a target="_blank" href="mailto:hello@hackertronix.com">
        <img src="images/mail-icon.svg" class="social-img">
     </a>
</div>
```

Link to the website: https://hackertronix.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using following code twitter and dribble anchors workon mobile:

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 #section4 .right {
    z-index: 50;
  }
}
```